# Refining Productivity & Efficiency Query

Tags: sql-server, count, time, max

I'm trying to write a query that is, in effect, a Productivity and Efficiency Report for measuring the statistics of those of us (such as myself) who type up the paper work orders that our mechanics fill out when repairing our buses.

Here's a drawing of the report's layout:

```
              +------------------------------------------++-------------------------------------------------------+
              |                  DAILY                   ||                       MONTHLY                         |
+-------------+-------+-------+----------+-------+-------++-------+------------+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| Creator     | Count |  Time |  Average |  Min. |  Max. || Count | Daily Avg. |  Time |  Average |  Min. |  Max. |
+-------------+-------+-------+----------+-------+-------++-------+------------+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| williamsonb |    42 |  3:56 | 00:08:34 | 00:02 | 00:34 ||   ... |        ... |   ... |      ... |   ... |   ... |
| petersonl   |   ... |   ... |      ... |   ... |   ... ||   ... |        ... |   ... |      ... |   ... |   ... |
| ...         |   ... |   ... |      ... |   ... |   ... ||   ... |        ... |   ... |      ... |   ... |   ... |
+-------------+-------+-------+----------+-------+-------++-------+------------+-------+----------+-------+-------+
```

Here's how our software "works" (if you could call it that): If I were to open a window to start typing up a work order that one of our mechanic had just completed and I didn't wait until I had ALL of the information for that work order typed in before I clicked 'Save', and then continued typing the rest of the information, if 'petersonl' started typing up another work order after I had initially clicked 'Save' and also finished typing theirs before me the system would prevent them from clicking 'Save' until I was finished with my work order. It's incredibly annoying.

If I created a Work Order at 9:00 AM, petersonl created one at 9:30 AM, I started another at 10:00 AM, and then she started another at 10:15 AM, the duration of my first Work Order would be 1:00:00, whereas the duration of her first work order would be 00:45:00 . The query would look at the time between the work orders that distinct users have created/updated, like f(n+1)-f(n).

We finally got some laptops so that the mechanics will VERY soon be able to start inputting the parts used on a work order themselves, if any (meaning that this query will then need to shift from analyzing CreatedTime to UpdatedTime for those in data entry who STILL have to type in the mechanic's/s' notes), meaning our inventory will be more accurate from moment to the next, but if/when we start having the mechanics type ALL of their work directly into the database this report will need to be modified to conditionally analyze CreatedTime and UpdatedTime (if not null). However, considering that's likely not going to happen for at least another year or two...

Below is the SQL code for what I have *so far*:

```
CREATE TABLE WorkOrders(CreatedBy CHAR(25), CreatedTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO WorkOrders values
('williamsonb', '2017/03/26 12:05:00.000 PM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/26 12:12:00.000 PM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/26 01:31:00.000 PM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/02 09:45:00.000 AM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/02 09:49:00.000 AM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/02 09:51:00.000 AM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/02/04 02:14:00.000 PM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/26 07:42:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/26 07:45:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/26 07:46:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/05 08:47:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/05 08:49:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/05 08:50:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/01/17 06:54:00.000 AM');
```

> ```
> DECLARE 
>   @DayCount INT = COUNT(SELECT CreatedBy
>                         FROM   WorkOrders
>                         WHERE  CreatedTime = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()),
>
>   @DayTimeSum DECIMAL = SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, SELECT (HOUR(CreatedTime) 
>                                            FROM   WorkOrders 
>                                            WHERE  DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())) 
>                         + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, SELECT (MINUTE(CreationDate)/60 
>                                            FROM   WorkOrders 
>                                            WHERE  DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())) 
>                         + DATEDIFF(SECOND, SELECT (SECOND(CreationDate)/3600 
>                                            FROM   WorkOrders 
>                                            WHERE  DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()))),
>
>   @DaySumHours INT = @DayTimeSum - MOD(@DayTimeSum % 1),
>
>   @DaySumMinutes INT = (MOD(@DayTimeSum % 1) - MOD(MOD(@DayTimeSum % 1) % 1/60) ) * 60,
>
>   @DayAvgTime DECIMAL = @DayCount / @DayTimeSum,
>
>   @DayAvgHours INT = @DayAvgTime - MOD(@DayAvgTime % 1),
>
>   @DayAvgMinutes INT = (MOD(@DayAvgTime % 1) - MOD(MOD(@DayAvgTime % 1) % 1/60)) * 60,
>
>   @DayAvgSeconds INT = ((MOD(@DayAvgTime % 1) 
>                         - MOD(MOD(@DayAvgTime % 1) % 1/60)) 
>                         - MOD((MOD(@DayAvgTime % 1) 
>                         - MOD(MOD(@DayAvgTime % 1) % 1/60) ) % 1/3600) ) * 3600,
>
>   @MonthTimeSum DECIMAL = SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, SELECT (HOUR(CreatedTime) 
>                                              FROM   WorkOrders 
>                                              WHERE  DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) 
>                           + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, SELECT (MINUTE(CreationDate)/60 
>                                              FROM   WorkOrders 
>                                              WHERE  DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) 
>                           + DATEDIFF(SECOND, SELECT (SECOND(CreationDate)/3600 
>                                              FROM   WorkOrders 
>                                              WHERE  DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())));
>
>     SELECT   DISTINCT CreatedBy
>              ,@DayCount AS [Count]
>              ,@DaySumHours + ':' + @DaySumMinutes + ':' + @DaySumSeconds AS [Total]
>              ,@DayAvgHours + ':' + @DayAvgMinutes + ':' + @DayAvgSeconds AS [Average]
>              ,LAST(SELECT CAST(SELECT CAST(CreatedTime AS TIME) AS CHAR(5))) AS [Min.]
>              ,TOP 1(CAST(SELECT CAST(CreatedTime AS TIME) AS CHAR(5))) AS [Max.]
>     FROM     WorkOrders
>     WHERE    CreatedTime BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
>     GROUP BY CreatedBy
>     ORDER BY CreatedTime DESC;
> ```
>
> At the very least I'm having trouble working out the 'Min.' and 'Max.' columns.

**Notes:**

1. If you're scratching your head wondering why I chose to use so many variables, I'm still working this query out- it wouldn't surprise me if there are ways to optimize this report computation-wise.
2. I'm not sure how to go about obtaining a reasonable list of the time duration between each CreationTime, and I know there is no way to get the duration for the very last Work Ordered entered each day, but that's tolerable.
3. The ReportBuilder interface built into our shop's software uses... Delphi? However, I'm pretty confident that our Technology Dept. uses Microsoft SQL Server for upkeep on the database, but I don't have permission to get software that powerful installed on my computer.
4. The reason the 'Average' columns have the time format HH:MM:SS and yet the 'Time', 'Min.', and 'Max.' columns are of the format HH:MM is because when CreatedTime is recorded in our software it always comes out in the format HH:MM:00.000 .
5. I went ahead and let the 'Average' columns have seconds soas to make the read-out more differentiated from everything else.
6. CreatedTime is the time that progress on the work order was first saved to the system. There is another field called UpdatedTime which deals with the datetime when the work order was modified after its creation, and stays null until a work order that has been saved for the first time is edited, then saved again.

Comment: I would seriously question the value of the report you are writing. As i understand it, it doesn't reflect how long you actually spend entering  a WO. It doesnt reflect taking breaks or the complexity of in WO vs the next. You might as well take thier first and last times and divide by the number. Assuming the updatedtime is set when you click save you would be better off working out the duration for each WO by subtracting the createdtime from the updated time. Then work out count, max, min, avg duration per user.

Comment: Actually, I think @Peter is making the same point I brought up. However, this may be a matter of misunderstanding what you're actually measuring. I think many readers thought you were measuring the time it took to fulfill a work order. Now, I think I understand better. Your mechanics complete a work order in full on paper, and then you have to type it into the system. It's the time it takes to enter it into the system that you're trying to measure, which makes more sense.

Comment: Do you want to ignore the last work order of the day, or assume it was completed at EOD (let's say, 17:00)?

Comment: Can you confirm that the SQL you've shown above is pencil and paper stuff? it seems to involve some functions that don't exist, and assume that you can `DECLARE` and set a variable, and then reference it when setting another variable in the same `DECLARE`, which doesn't work.

Comment: @RDFozz - It was more pen-and-paper kind of stuff. I'm guessing that if the resulting list of work order processing times where sorted by their duration, the TOP 1 and LAST expressions could probably be used to get the 'Min.' and 'Max.' times, but I couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

All right - I think this will get you most of the way there. NOTE: I'm using some of the same things as Paparazzi, but put this together from scratch myself. I've tried to make some of the steps obvious, so it's entirely possible his solution would be faster.

```
-- Test Data
CREATE TABLE #WorkOrders(CreatedBy CHAR(25), CreatedTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #WorkOrders values
('williamsonb', '2017/03/27 12:05:00.000 PM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/27 12:12:00.000 PM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/27 01:31:00.000 PM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/26 09:04:00.000 PM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/26 09:12:00.000 PM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/26 10:32:00.000 PM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/02 09:45:00.000 AM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/02 09:49:00.000 AM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/03/02 09:51:00.000 AM'),
('williamsonb', '2017/02/04 02:14:00.000 PM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/27 07:42:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/27 07:45:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/27 07:46:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/26 08:41:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/26 08:46:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/26 08:48:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/05 08:47:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/05 08:49:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/03/05 08:50:00.000 AM'),
('petersonl',   '2017/01/17 06:54:00.000 AM'); 



WITH BaseData AS
     (SELECT CreatedBy
            ,CreatedTime
            ,LEAD(CreatedTime,1) OVER (PARTITION BY CreatedBy, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedTime) ORDER BY CreatedTime) as EndTime
        FROM #WorkOrders
     )
--SELECT * FROM BaseData
    ,DataWDuration AS
     (SELECT CreatedBy
            ,CreatedTime
            ,EndTime
            ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreatedTime, EndTime) < 60 THEN 60 ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND, CreatedTime, EndTime) END as Duration
        FROM BaseData
     )
    ,DayTotal AS
     (SELECT CreatedBy
            ,COUNT(*) as dailyCount
            ,SUM(Duration) as dailyTimeSec
            ,AVG(Duration) as DailyAvgTimeSec
            ,MIN(Duration) as DailyMinTimeSec
            ,MAX(Duration) as DailyMaxTimeSec
        FROM DataWDuration
       WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedTime) = DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) -- compares date part of CreatedTime with yesterday's date
       GROUP BY CreatedBy
     )
    ,MTDTotal AS
     (SELECT CreatedBy
            ,COUNT(*) as mtdCount
            ,COUNT(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedTime)) as ActiveDays
            ,COUNT(*) * 1.0 / DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) as mtdAvgDailyCount
            ,COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedTime)) as mtdActiveDayAvgCount
            ,SUM(Duration) as mtdTimeSec
            ,AVG(Duration) as mtdAvgTimeSec
            ,MIN(Duration) as mtdMinTimeSec
            ,MAX(Duration) as mtdMaxTimeSec
        FROM DataWDuration
       WHERE CreatedTime >= DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())), CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) as datetime)) -- picks up all activity for current calendar month to date
         AND CreatedTime < DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) -- ignore anything entered today.
       GROUP BY CreatedBy
     )
SELECT *
  FROM DayTotal dt
         FULL JOIN MTDTotal mt ON (dt.CreatedBy = mt.CreatedBy)
;
```

So, the first part is just creating some data to work with. I took what you had provided, and added data for 3/27 (so there would be something from yesterday to look at).

Next, you see the query. I broke down the process using CTEs (Common Table Expressions), which are basically sub-queries you can reference in multiple places in your query (with a few bonus features, like recursive CTEs, but that's not necessary for this). If you want to see exactly what any of the CTE's returns, comment out everything after that CTE, put in `SELECT * FROM` and the CTE name; see the example right below the `BaseData` CTE.

The `BaseData` CTE adds an end time for each of the `WorkOrder` rows. Note that the end time for the last work order on any given day is NULL. As Paparazzi suggested, the `LEAD` functions helps us out here; it gives us the `CreatedTime` of the next record to use as the `EndTime` of the current record. The `OVER` clause is what makes this work; it tells SQL to just use the records for a specific `CreatedBy`, for a specific date, ordered by `CreatedTime`.

We need to find all the records for a specific date, regardless of the time, so we need a way to strip the time out of `CreatedTime`. There are a number of ways to do this. The fastest way is `CAST(CreatedTime as DATE)`; however, this only works with SQL Server 2008 and up, and I wasn't certain what version you had. The second fastest way is supposed to be `CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedTime) as datetime)`. This uses the fact that dates are stored as floating point integers, with the number left of the decimal point representing the date part and the number right of the decimal point representing the time part. So, we get the number of days between the date represented by 0 and today, then we have the server cast that to a datetime value. We get today's date, with the time set to midnight.  If you are using SQL 2008 or later, I'd replace this with casting the datetime value to datatype `DATE`.

Note that when we just need to compare two dates, the number of days value works as well as the actual date, so we save some processing by not doing the final `CAST` to `datetime`.

The `LEAD` function accepts three arguments - the field to look at; how many rows ahead to look; and the default value to use if there is no row there. The default for the third argument is NULL; that works with what we're doing, so we just used that.

A final note on `BaseData`: this would be a good point to limit the rows you're bringing back. I didn't, because the test data is small, and because I'm not sure that you're not ultimately going to want to use this to pull back quarterly or annual results. We do put limits in later, for the specific subtotals you want. However, I would recommend limiting the rows you look at in practice, as prepping a year's worth of data to get monthly totals would take much longer than necessary.

The `DataWDuration` simply adds the amount of time (in seconds) that each work order took to process. You could combine this with the previous step, but the SQL gets really hard to follow, and I wanted to avoid that. Again, the last work order of each day has a NULL `EndTime`, and that means it has a NULL `Duration`.

The `DayTotal` CTE gives us the requested values for everyone who worked yesterday. Since we have an entry for each work order, getting `MIN` and `MAX` are straight-forward, as are the `COUNT` and `AVG`.

Two notes here: `COUNT(*)` gives you the total number of rows in your selection (for each group from `GROUP BY`). `COUNT(Duration)`, on the other hand, would only count the rows where `Duration` was not NULL. I'm assuming that, even though we have to ignore the last work order of the day for the purposes of `MIN`, `MAX`, and `AVG`, we want it included in the count.

Also, we're using that "number of days" trick again to find the data for yesterday. Just like `DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedTime)` gives us the date part of `CreatedTime`, `DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())` gives us the date part of today's date. However, we actually want the date part of yesterday's date. So, we want the number of days between the zero date and today's date - 1; which, it turns out, is the same as the number of days between the date that corresponds to day 1, and today's date. Keep this in mind if you're looking to replace this method with the "CAST as DATE" method.

Next, we have the `MTDTotal` (for Month-To-Date) CTE. I wasn't sure how you were defining a month, so I went with this. If you want to use `DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())` (SQL's definition of "one month ago"), or `DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())`, you should be able to modify this appropriately.

How you'd want to calculate the daily average number of work orders wasn't 100% clear, so I gave you two options. The first calculates the average based on the number of work orders by the person, divided by the number of days in the month so far (again, you should be able to adjust this for a different definition of month, if necessary). The second gives the average number of work orders per day that this particular person worked. So, if Ms. Peterson did 21 work orders on the 7 days she worked, and you did 30 on the 10 days you worked, you'd both have an average of 3. You should be able to modify this to even figure out working days (based on dates where someone had a work order), by pulling `COUNT(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(DAY,0,CreatedTime)` for the same set of records we're looking at now (without a `GROUP BY`), by adding another CTE.

Again, just to cover it, the `WHERE` clause is restricting the query to rows where `CreatedTime` is midnight on the first day of the current month or later, but is before midnight today. We're using the "number of days" trick again, but actually casting the value to `datetime`. We move back to the first of the month by getting the "day" part of yesterday's date, and subtracting (day - 1) from the date (for instance, if today is April 1, then yesterday was March 31, to we subtract 30 days to get March 1; If today is April 2, then yesterday was April 1, so we subtract 0 days to get - April 1!).

As I alluded to above, you could add CTEs to give you quarterly or annual totals, if you wanted.

I used a FULL join to display the values, so that you would still see the monthly totals for someone who was out yesterday. I left formatting the seconds as time values up to you. I do have a recommendation; if you're translating the seconds to "HH:MM" (not "HH:MM:SS"), then add 30 seconds when you're doing your calculations; that will round the result up to the next minute (329 seconds = "00:05:29" would become "00:05"; 330 seconds = "00:05:30" would become "00:06").

Results shown below (I manually edited out the second `CreatedBy` column, and of course using the column names rather than `*` would have prevented it altogether):

```
CreatedBy       dailyCount  dailyTimeSec DailyAvgTimeSec DailyMinTimeSec DailyMaxTimeSec mtdCount    ActiveDays  mtdAvgDailyCount      mtdActiveDayAvgCount   mtdTimeSec  mtdAvgTimeSec mtdMinTimeSec mtdMaxTimeSec
--------------- ----------- ------------ --------------- --------------- --------------- ----------- ----------- --------------------- ---------------------- ----------- ------------- ------------- -------------
petersonl       3           240          120             60              180             9           3           0.321428571428        3.000000000000         840         140           60            300
williamsonb     3           5160         2580            420             4740            9           3           0.321428571428        3.000000000000         10800       1800          120           4800
```

Hope this helps.

[EDIT: updated the calculation of Duration to ensure that any values less than 60 seconds are bumped up to 60 seconds; NULL values remain NULL].

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57184/discussion-on-answer-by-rdfozz-refining-productivity-efficiency-query).

Answer (score 0):

Here is part

```
select cast(CreatedTime as Date) as CreatedDate, CreatedBy      
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), min(CreatedTime), 108) as [start]
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), max(CreatedTime), 108) as [stop]
     , datediff(MINUTE, min(CreatedTime), MAX(CreatedTime)) as [start-stop]
     , count(*) as count
     , cast(datediff(MINUTE, min(CreatedTime), MAX(CreatedTime)) / cast((count(*) - 1) as decimal) as decimal(6,2)) as [avg] 
from WorkOrders 
group by cast(CreatedTime as Date), CreatedBy 
having count(*) > 1 
union 
select cast(CreatedTime as Date) as CreatedDate, CreatedBy     
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), max(CreatedTime), 108) 
     , null
     , null
     , count(*) as count
     , null 
from WorkOrders 
group by cast(CreatedTime as Date), CreatedBy 
having count(*) = 1 
order by cast(CreatedTime as Date) desc, CreatedBy
```

This has everything you need

```
select [CreatedDate], CreatedBy
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CreatedTime, 108)   as [time]     
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [min], 108)         as [min]
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [max], 108)         as [max]
     , datediff(MINUTE, [min], [max])          as [min-max]
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [next], 108)        as [next]
     , datediff(MINUTE, [next], [CreatedTime]) as [time-next]
     , [count] 
     , [first], [last]
from 
( select CreatedBy, cast(CreatedTime as date) as [CreatedDate], CreatedTime 
       , LEAD(CreatedTime) OVER (PARTITION BY CreatedBy, cast(CreatedTime as date) ORDER BY CreatedTime desc) AS [next]
       , min(CreatedTime)  OVER (PARTITION BY CreatedBy, cast(CreatedTime as date) ORDER BY CreatedTime)      AS [min]
       , max(CreatedTime)  OVER (PARTITION BY CreatedBy, cast(CreatedTime as date) ORDER BY CreatedTime)      AS [max]     
       , COUNT(*)          OVER (PARTITION BY CreatedBy, cast(CreatedTime as date))                           AS [count]
       , ROW_NUMBER()      OVER (PARTITION BY CreatedBy, cast(CreatedTime as date) ORDER BY CreatedTime)      AS [last]
       , ROW_NUMBER()      OVER (PARTITION BY CreatedBy, cast(CreatedTime as date) ORDER BY CreatedTime desc) AS [first]
  from WorkOrders 
) tt
-- where tt.first = 1 or tt.last = 1
order by tt.CreatedDate desc, CreatedBy
```